# Transition between volume_up and volume_down icons

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Taking the two icons volume_up and volume_down from https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline

I want to achieve the same effect as the gif below in flutter.

[image]

To note, I am using bloc architecture so pretty much everything is Stateless and would prefer avoiding Stateful widgets.

The animation should be infinite duration.

I cannot figure out a simple way to essentially swap between two icons on an infinite loop using animations (and a plus would be for a nice fade in/out effect).

I thought about using a Timer and swapping between the two icons but that seems a rather basic hack for what *should* be a tried and tested functionality.

Does anyone have a code solution to achieve what the gif shows or can point me to an example doing the same thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use AnimatedSwitcher switch between images and control the duration by Timer
[AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html)